# Joining tables in SQL in one row

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have the following table structure of my database:

[db structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h033q.jpg)

My aim is to output every row of tbl_Therapeuten (these are my employees) with the name of their trainings (in german "Fortbildung").
The names of the trainings are stored in tbl_Forbildungen. And the trainings which each employee has is stores in tbl_Therapeut_Fortbildung. For the output I want to show the name of the training, not the id.
Like this:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0cjQ.jpg)

I am programming in C#, SQL Server.
First I tried this:

```
string sSQL = "SELECT t.*, STRING_AGG(tf.Id_Fortbildung, ';') AS Fortbildungen " +
              "FROM tbl_Therapeuten t " +
              "FULL OUTER JOIN tbl_Therapeut_Fortbildung tf on t.Id = tf.Id_Therapeut ";
```

But this brings an error containing that I don't use tbl_Therapeuten.Id in an aggregate function or in a Group by clause.

Next I tried this:

```
string sSQL = "SELECT t.Id, t.Nachname, STRING_AGG(tf.Id_Fortbildung, ';') AS Fortbildungen " +
              "FROM tbl_Therapeuten t " +
              "FULL OUTER JOIN tbl_Therapeut_Fortbildung tf on t.Id = tf.Id_Therapeut " +
              "GROUP BY t.Id, t.Nachname";
```

This worked (except displaying the name of the training but the Id) but I don't want to explicitly name every column of tbl_Therapeuten. I want to use "t.*". But this is not working:

```
string sSQL = "SELECT t.*, STRING_AGG(tf.Id_Fortbildung, ';') AS Fortbildungen " +
              "FROM tbl_Therapeuten t " +
              "FULL OUTER JOIN tbl_Therapeut_Fortbildung tf on t.Id = tf.Id_Therapeut " +
              "GROUP BY t.*";
```

So I need some help :)

And what I also don't know how to do is to display the name of the trainings instead of the id.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not as images (or links to images.) Also take a look at [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find that a correlated subquery provides better performance (by avoiding the outer aggregation) and allows you to avoid listing all columns from `t`:

```
SELECT T.*,
       (SELECT STRING_AGG(F.Name, ';')
        FROM tbl_Therapeut_FortBildung TF JOIN
             tbl_FortBildungen F 
             ON F.Id = TF.Id_FortBildung
        WHERE TF.Id_Therapeut = T.Id
       ) as Fortbildungen
FROM Therapeuten T
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need.

```
SELECT T.Id,T.Name,T.Street,T.BirthDate,STRING_AGG(F.Name,';')
FROM Therapeuten T 
LEFT JOIN tbl_Therapeut_FortBildung TF ON TF.Id_Therapeut=T.Id
LEFT JOIN tbl_FortBildungen F ON F.Id=TF.Id_FortBildung
GROUP BY T.Id,T.Name,T.Street,T.BirthDate
```

As far as I know SQL server does not support the GROUP BY *, so you will have to specify the column names.

Comment: That is how it works in MySQL but this is a SQL Server question. Can you link to any documentation ?

Comment: You are right SQL Server does require columns in the SELECT to be matched in the GROUP BY (unless they are aggregated)  - that should be explained to OP